# Passing an array to a query using a WHERE clause - works in phpmyadmin, not in my script

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I've searched for the answer online, if I've missed something obvious, I would appreciate links. Otherwise, I'd be grateful for direct help. This is the first time I've ever tried a query like this.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `dice_t` WHERE qty IN (:qty) AND opacity IN (:opacity) AND color IN (:color)
```

To which I am feeding the following array:

```
Array
(
    [qty] => 1,2
    [opacity] => 3
    [color] => 467,1007
)
```

It works perfectly (retrieves 163 rows) in phpMyAdmin (when I type in the values), but in my script, it retrieves only 114 rows, which corresponds to it using only the first value in each field (i.e. qty: 1; opacity: 3; color: 467). I have verified this by running the query with only those values in phpMyAdmin.

My code looks like this:

```
$statement = $dbConn->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute($queryData);
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

When I print the values of $sql and $queryData I get the values listed in the first two code blocks above.

The fields are all integers. I tried searching with single quotes around the values, but got an error.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition) Can you see the end result? What is the SQL sent to the database from your code? Share that. Or compare to what you've used in phpmyadmin, they must differ.

Comment: Well that's interesting! If I type it out without using the array (just copy-paste from phpMyAdmin), it works. So it's not reading anything past the comma in each field. Any idea why that might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Varable :qty is handled as Strinf So you have '1,1'

So you must use `FIND_IN_SET`

```
SELECT * FROM `dice_t` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`qty`,:qty) AND  FIND_ON_SET(`opacity`,:opacity) AND  FIND_IN_SET(`color`,:color)
```

other ways are in this thread [Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)

Comment: AFAIK, FIND_IN_SET doesn't use indexes, hence this is not a solution but a landmine under the future performance.

Comment: The solutions presented in the links take a comma separated  stirng and split it and make  a more or minus huge `IN` IN  is slow for huge data and FIND_IN_SET isn't that much slower.

Comment: what? what do you mean, "slow"? got any proof?

Comment: that is my experience with big databses, so i use normally INNER JOINS ibstead IN Clause, if you got to that point try a join, But for a small amount of ids, it doesn't matter

Comment: so you don't have any proof. that was quite expected.

Comment: i recoment to try it with a million rows generated and then to try it increasing the number of IN elements. Try it

Comment: I have some knowledge. In how databases work. I don't need your homebrewed tests. There is not a single reason for IN to be slow with a properly configured database. And I even have some experience. That tells me that your fear for IN is coming from a completely DIFFERENT case where you were using it with a SELECT subquery. That indeed could be slow. Have a nice day and try not to spread misinformation.